# Detect when mouse is pressed in a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I got macro that put "X" into empty cell after mouse click in specified range. I used `Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange` to do that and everything works fine. Now I want to detect when someone holds mouse clicked more than 1s on that cell and put in cell "Y". Is there any way to do that? Can I run some event when I click on cell and run another event when I release the button and then calculate time between both events?

My code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("C38:AZ49")) Is Nothing Then
            If IsEmpty(Target.Value) Then
                Target.Value = "X"
            EndIf
            Cells(Target.Row, 1).Select
    End If
```

If i click on cell -> "X"
If i hold click > 1 second -> "Y"

Comment: I guess you could start a timer based on [`MouseDown`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/mousedown-mouseup-events), but I don't think that you can trigger it with `SelectionChange`, since it only activates **after** the mouse button has gone up. You'd have to always be timing mouseDown, which could make it not worth it

Comment: But I can't use MouseDown on empty cell